# Convert list values from float to int in python

Tags: python, list, integer, tuples, rounding

I have the following list:

```
lst = [(22027.0, 22943.0),
 (22026.0, 22939.0),
 (22025.0, 22936.0),
 (22025.0, 22932.0),
 (22027.0, 22929.0),
 (22030.0, 22926.0),
 (22031.0, 22922.0),
 (22033.0, 22919.0),
 (22033.0, 22907.0),
 (22030.0, 22908.0),
 (22029.0, 22911.0),
 (22027.0, 22914.0),
 (22025.0, 22918.0),
 (22021.0, 22930.0),
 (22018.0, 22931.0),
 (22015.0, 22928.0),
 (22012.0, 22924.0),
 (22011.0, 22921.0),
 (22011.33, 22920.0)]
```

I would like to convert this list values to int. I tried using round but it gives me the following error. What I tried so far?

```
[round(i) for i in lst]
```

I get the following error `TypeError: type tuple doesn't define __round__ method`

Desired output:

```
[(22027, 22943),
 (22026, 22939),
 (22025, 22936),
 (22025, 22932),
 (22027, 22929),
 (22030, 22926),
 (22031, 22922),
 (22033, 22919),
 (22033, 22907),
 (22030, 22908),
 (22029, 22911),
 (22027, 22914),
 (22025, 22918),
 (22021, 22930),
 (22018, 22931),
 (22015, 22928),
 (22012, 22924),
 (22011, 22921),
 (22011, 22920)]
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable. The values inside can't be changed. You have to apply round inside both the elements of the tuple.

Comment: you are trying to convert tuple into int, you can do this `[tuple(map(int, x)) for x in lst]`

Comment: You have a tuple as element so you should `[(round(a), round(b)) for a, b in lst]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension, each element inside the list is tuple, so you need to take them into account individually, also you can use `int()` instead of `round()` to convert floating point number to integer:

```py
[(int(x), int(y)) for x,y in lst]

[(22027, 22943), (22026, 22939), (22025, 22936), (22025, 22932), (22027, 22929), (22030, 22926), (22031, 22922), (22033, 22919), (22033, 22907), (22030, 22908), (22029, 22911), (22027, 22914), (22025, 22918), (22021, 22930), (22018, 22931), (22015, 22928), (22012, 22924), (22011, 22921), (22011, 22920)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [(87.8,68.9),(122.0,68.4),(178.9,63.4),(245.6,68.1)]
y =[]
for i in x:  
    b = tuple(map(int, i))
    y.append(b)
print(y)
```